# How do I skip a tests file if it is run on systems with go 1.4 and below?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a file containing some tests that should be run on Go 1.5+.

I am able to get the Go runtime version using `runtime.Version()` and doing various comparisons.

However, the test file imports `golang.org/x/net/http2`. The `http2` package requires `request.Cancel()` from `net/http`, but that is only available on Go 1.5+.

That causes these errors in my CI environment causing the build to fail:

```
../../../golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:214: req.Cancel undefined (type *http.Request has no field or method Cancel)
../../../golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:218: req.Cancel undefined (type *http.Request has no field or method Cancel)
../../../golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:777: req.Cancel undefined (type *http.Request has no field or method Cancel)
```

I tried adding `// +build go1.5` to the top of the file, but it didn't work.

Is there anyway I can limit a unit test file so that it is built and tested only on Go 1.5+ systems?

Comment: I have no problem with including build directive at the top of my test files (`// +build ignore` successfully ignores the broken test file), but I'm running go 1.6. Silly question: have you added a blank line between the `build` directive and the name of the package ? If not they're not taken into account (guess they're considered as documentation).

Comment: That was it! I neglected the blank line and it thought the built directive was documentation. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) is the proper way to do it.

But note that your error messages refer to the `http2` package which was [added in Go 1.6](https://golang.org/doc/go1.6#http2), so you need at least `go1.6` build constraint.

The build constraint

```
// +build go1.5
```

Will cause the file to be compiled with **Go 1.5 and onward**. So if you want your test file to only compile and run with Go 1.6 and above, then use

```
// +build go1.6
```

Also don't forget that:

> Constraints may appear in any kind of source file (not just Go), but they must appear **near the top of the file, preceded only by blank lines and other line comments**. These rules mean that in Go files a build constraint must appear before the package clause.
>
> To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, **a series of build constraints must be followed by a blank line**.

A working example:

```
1  // +build go1.6
2
3  package yourpackage
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that go1.17 onward supports a new build tag format that has a more explicit syntax and which go fmt is aware of: See https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints for full details.

```
//go:build go1.17
```

(don't forget the newline after the build constraint)